# Cannot find json file to load on ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, json, angular, three.js

i am trying to load a external model from blender on a angular app using threeJS, and i follow [this](https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2015/07/27/importing-blender-modelized-mesh-in-threejs.html) tutorial for that. The problem is, when i reach the point where i need to load the external file:

```
loader.load('./marmelab-logo.json', function(geometry) {
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
    mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 0.75;
    mesh.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
    scene.add(mesh);
});
```

the json is never found, the path is correct but it can't find the file, dunno why.

**This is what i currently have:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import * as dama from "./dama.json";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }
  private container: HTMLElement;

  @ViewChild('container') elementRef: ElementRef;
  private scene: THREE.Scene;
  private camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
  private renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;

  private cube: THREE.Mesh;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.container = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

    console.log(this.container);

    this.init();
    this.http
  }

  init() {
    let screen = {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
      color: 0xffffff
    },
      view = {
        angle: 45,
        aspect: screen.width / screen.height,
        near: 0.1,
        far: 1000
      };

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(view.angle, view.aspect, view.near, view.far);
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    this.renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 1);

    this.scene.add(this.camera);
    this.scene.add(new THREE.AxisHelper(20));

    this.camera.position.set(10, 10, 10);
    this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    this.renderer.setSize(screen.width, screen.height);
    this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    var mesh = null;
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

    this.http.get("http://localhost:4200/assets/dama.json")


    loader.load('./dama.json', function (geometry) {
      mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
      this.scene.add(mesh);
    });

    let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5),
      material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF, wireframe: true });

    this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.cube.position.set(-50, -50, -50);

    this.scene.add(this.cube);

    this.render();
  }

  render() {

    let self: AppComponent = this;

    (function render() {
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      self.renderer.render(self.scene, self.camera);
      self.renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1);

      self.animate();
    }());

  }

  onResize(event) {
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }

  animate() {
    this.cube.rotateX(0.1);
    this.cube.rotateY(0.1);
    this.cube.position.addScalar(0.2);

  }


}
```

Comment: Does Threejs itself work correctly in your application?

Comment: _"the json is never found"_ explains nothing. Any error/warning message(s) in the browser console?

Comment: :4200/dama.json Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found),yes ThreeJs works well

Comment: Are you sure that dama.json is in the same folder where index.html is located? Or, is it in the assets folder? Please share the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, `this.http.get("http://localhost:4200/assets/dama.json")` I guess that the json file is located in the assets folder.

If your folder structure is like the one below,

-assets

- dama.json

-index.html

then you can try this,

```
loader.load('assets/dama.json', function (geometry) { 
//rest of your code. 
});
```